# Obtaining Object Coordinates in Fabric.js: Actual Coordinates vs Bounding Rectangles

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Could you please help me understand how to obtain the actual coordinates of an object in fabric.js, rather than its bounding rectangle?

[image: Triangle - find actual coordinates]

[image: Parallelogram - find actual coordinates]

`getBoundingRect` is there to get the boundingBox coordinates. But I don't find any method or custom approach to find the actual shape coordinates as shown the below pictures.

I am using *fabric 5.*

```js
const fc = new fabric.Canvas("c");


fc.on('selection:created', event => {
    console.log("Bounding Rect: ", event.target.item(0).getBoundingRect());
    console.log("How to find actual coord?? ");
});


const triangle1Options = {
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 2,
    fill: 'red',
    left: 10,
    top: 10,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
}

let triangle1 = new fabric.Triangle(triangle1Options);

const group1 = new fabric.Group([triangle1], {
      selectable: true,
      lockScalingFlip: true,
      lockUniScaling: true,
      subTargetCheck: true,
      lockScalingX: false,
      lockScalingY: false,
      objectCaching: false,
      noScaleCache: true
});

group1.add(triangle1);

fc.add(group1);


// Create the first parallelogram
var parallelogram1 = new fabric.Path('M 0 0 L 100 0 L 150 50 L 50 50 z', {
    left: 150,
    top: 50,
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 2,
    fill: 'red',
});
const group2 = new fabric.Group([parallelogram1], {
      selectable: true,
      lockScalingFlip: true,
      lockUniScaling: true,
      subTargetCheck: true,
      lockScalingX: false,
      lockScalingY: false,
      objectCaching: false,
      noScaleCache: true
});


// Add the shapes and line to the canvas
fc.add(group2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.1.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="300" />
```

Any help is highly appreciated. I am open for new ideas for achieving my goal which is mentioned below.

**Goal** by this is to create an additional shape (a rect with text) on each vertex mid. but for that I need the actual coordinates of the shape.

Answer (score 0):

To find out the vertex coordinates it's easier to work with `fabric.Polygon` instead of `fabric.Rect` or `fabric.Triangle`. With polygons we can directly access the points that form it, plus we can create triangles and rectangles with them.

Basically you need the points of the polygon and transform them from the object plane to the canvas plane, that way you get the coordinates relative to the canvas.

The function below does that. It takes a `fabric.Polygon` as an argument and returns the vertices in the canvas plane.

```
function getPolyVertices(poly) {
  const points = poly.points,
    vertices = [];

  points.forEach((point) => {
    const x = point.x - poly.pathOffset.x,
      y = point.y - poly.pathOffset.y;

    vertices.push(
      fabric.util.transformPoint(
        { x: x, y: y },
        fabric.util.multiplyTransformMatrices(
          poly.canvas.viewportTransform,
          poly.calcTransformMatrix()
        )
      )
    );
  });

  return vertices;
}
```

If you want to better understand how this function works and see an example of it working (like the image below), I suggest reading [this article here](https://medium.com/@luizzappa/how-to-find-out-the-coordinates-of-vertices-of-a-shape-in-fabric-js-a871109085c1). *Disclosure*: I'm the author of this article.

[image]